# How to re-arrange QTableView's Columns Order

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtableview

The code below creates a single QTableView driven by Model/Proxy framework.

The `self.headerNames` list-variable declared in `source-model` stores the names of the Header's Columns. The number of names in this list is used by the same `source model`'s `columnCount()` method to return the number of column in a view:

```
def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    return len(self.headerNames)
```

The `Proxy` model's `headerData()` access this `self.headerNames` variable via `source model`:

```
sourceModel=self.sourceModel()
```

On `if role==Qt.DisplayRole` the Proxy retrieves and returns the name of the column to QTableView:

```
return QVariant( sourceModel.headerNames[column] )
```

There is a right-click menu implemented on header-column right-click.
That portion is working fine. But since I could not find any examples on how others do it I had to design how it would work myself. I would appreciate if you find it could be improved.

What I want to implement next is the ability to re-arrange the column in arbitrary order. But I am not sure where to start.

[image]

P.s. Please disregard the names of the Items displayed in QTableView.
I wanted to keep the code as simple as possible focusing on Header/Column subject only here.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_A_001','Item_A_002','Item_B_001','Item_B_002']
        self.headerNames=['Column 0','Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4','Column 5','Column 6','Column 7']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.headerNames)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()

class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        return True

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        sourceModel=self.sourceModel()

        if role==Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if orientation==Qt.Horizontal:
                return QVariant(int(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter))
            return QVariant(int(Qt.AlignHCenter|Qt.AlignVCenter))

        if role==Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation==Qt.Horizontal:
                return QVariant( sourceModel.headerNames[column] )
            else:
                return QVariant()
        else:
            return QVariant()

        return QVariant(int(column+1))


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tableModel=Model(self)               

        proxyModel=Proxy()
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(tableModel)

        self.tableview=QTableView(self) 
        self.tableview.setModel(proxyModel)
        self.tableview.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableview.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

        header=self.tableview.horizontalHeader()
        header.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        header.connect(header, SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)" ), self.headerRightClicked)

        self.resHeaderMenu=QMenu(self)

        for column in range(proxyModel.columnCount()):
            columnName=proxyModel.headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal).toPyObject()
            actn=QAction('%s'%columnName, self.resHeaderMenu, checkable=True)
            actn.setChecked(True)
            actn.triggered.connect(self.resHeaderMenuTriggered)
            self.resHeaderMenu.addAction(actn)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableview)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def headerRightClicked(self, QPos):
        parentPosition=self.tableview.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0))        
        menuPosition=parentPosition + QPos
        self.resHeaderMenu.move(menuPosition)
        self.resHeaderMenu.show()        

    def resHeaderMenuTriggered(self, arg):
        print 'resHeaderMenuTriggered', arg
        for i, actn in enumerate(self.resHeaderMenu.actions()):
            if not actn.isChecked():
                self.tableview.setColumnHidden(i, True) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can switch on the ability to drag columns via [setMovable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#setMovable)? No need to implement this yourself...

Comment: `setMovable` seems to be obsolete in 5.11. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview-obsolete.html) lets you use `setSectionsMovable` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case you really want to re-arrange the columns yourself:

You can move or swap sections via the [moveSection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#moveSection) and [swapSections](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#swapSections) methods of the `horizontalHeader`.

```
headerView.moveSection(x, y)
```

will move column `x` such that it's column `y` afterwards, while

```
headerView.swapSections(x,y)
```

will - obviously - swap the positions of the two columns.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the right-click menu implemented on header-column right-click example. Right looking for the same function as you were. Just one thing that the column should be shown when the tick is re-checked, i.e. your `resHeaderMenuTriggered()` should be written as:

```
def resHeaderMenuTriggered(self, arg):
    print('resHeaderMenuTriggered', arg)
    for i, actn in enumerate(self.resHeaderMenu.actions()):
        if not actn.isChecked():
            self.proxyView.setColumnHidden(i, True)
        else:
            self.proxyView.setColumnHidden(i, False)
```